# Need to change inputs to a function before they are used?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a  function that intakes two lists which represent the digits of a natural number, in reverse and SUMS them. There may also be an arbitrary number of trailing 0's in the lists.

```
plus :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
-- Ex: "plus [0,1,2,0] [2,1,0]" meaning 210+12
```

I have 3 separate functions that perform different parts of the problem and I cant get them to work together:

---

`cleanString` puts the digits back in order (most significant first) and removes any extra 0's (`cleanString [0,1,2,0]` outputs `[2,1,0]`):

`fromDigits` takes a list like `[2,1,0]` and gives `210`:

then the actual "plus" function is where I cant get it to run the input lists through `cleanString` before they go into `fromDigits` and add the resulting two ints. Compile error at `fromDigits (x.cleanString)`.

---

```
cleanString :: [Integer]->[Integer]
--reverse the string, then trim any leading zeroes
cleanString x = dropWhile(<1) y where y=reverse x

fromDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
fromDigits xs = aux xs 0
    where aux [] acc = acc
          aux (x:xs) acc  = aux xs ((acc * 10) + x)

plus :: [Integer]->[Integer] -> Integer
plus x y = (fromDigits (x.cleanString))+(fromDigits (y.cleanString))
```

Comment: What's wrong with (fromDIgits (cleanString x)) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` isn't a function, so it doesn't make sense to `.` it with anything. You shouldn't be doing `x.cleanString`, but rather `cleanString x`. Same for `y`. With those changes, your program seems to work for me:

```
plus x y = (fromDigits (cleanString x))+(fromDigits (cleanString y))
```

If you want to use `.` even though you don't have to, you can, just on functions instead of on `x` or `y`:

```
plus x y = ((fromDigits.cleanString) x)+((fromDigits.cleanString) y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I wish I could upvote this but my reputation is too low, fixed my issue. edit: I can just doesnt change the visible score, thanks

Comment: For cases like this you can use the `Data.Function.on` combinator too! ```plus = (+) `on` (fromDigits . cleanString)```